# Register and Unregister the BroadcastReceiver in Application Class

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

I have a broadcast receiver Which is registered in the onCreate() method of Android Applcation class but How to unRegister the same

example

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("TIMEZONE_CHANGED"));
}
```

In the above code I have registered it in  the application onCreate() method and there is no onDestroy() / onStop() method in the Application class to unregister the broadcastReceiver.

How to achieve it

Comment: please check: Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks :  link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html

Answer (score 62):

You don't need to unregister if you'd like to listen for the entire time the app is running. From the docs (as of today):

> Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts as long as the app is running.

(https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html)

Comment: Thank you so much doc reference...This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

you should create a BaseActivity.

Example

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("TIMEZONE_CHANGED"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
}
```

And MainActivity extend BaseActivity

example:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am doing it but The Unregistration happens each and every time when I kill the I need to make the app listening even when it is in background

Comment: When you move to another activity, the event will triggered again for the second activity

Answer (score 2):

You can call unregister receiver inside Application class, only you just call like this

in your MainActivity inside of onDesctroy() method call

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).unregisterReceiver();
}
```

we create **unregisterReceiver()** method in your MyApplication class

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("TIMEZONE_CHANGED"));
    }

public void unregisterReceiver() {
     unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: This is fine but I have to show the Alert Dialog in when the TimeZone Changed Where i need to pass Activity Context to it so How I will do it

Comment: First, you need to update your question, what exactly your problem

Answer (score -2):

call this from where you want to unregister

```
unregisterReceiver();
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use statically registered broadcast receivers in your manifest which doesn't require you to call `registerReceiver()` and `unRegisterReceiver()`

```
<receiver
   android:name=".MyTimeChangeReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: This will not work in Android API 26+: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts